# Finding all JPA entities that are not referenced from another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @OneToMany
  private List<EntityB> b;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
  @Id
  private String id;

  ...
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is to define a `@NamedQuery` that retrieves all `EntityB` instances that are not referenced from any `EntityA`.

Naively, I would have tried

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EntityB.findAllUnassigned", query = "SELECT b FROM EntityB b WHERE NOT b IN (SELECT DISTINCT a.b FROM EntityA a)")
```

but this ends up generating invalid SQL:

```
select b0_.id as id1_, b0_.attr, ... from b b0_ where b0_.id not in  (select distinct . from a a1_, a_b ab2_, b b3_ where a1_.id=ab2_.a_id and ab2_.b_id=b3_.id)
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weird that this query does not give you an exception.  But your b.a reference is not legal in this way; you cannot select the collection itself, you want/need to select the collection elements.

```
SELECT b FROM EntityB b WHERE b NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT elements(a.b) FROM EntityA a)
```

Note however that elements is a Hibernate HQL construct, not JPA.

If you care about JPA portability:

```
SELECT b FROM EntityB b WHERE b NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b2 FROM EntityA a join a.b b2)
```

*** NOT IN is the more normal form, so I used that here as well

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by invalid SQL?
did you actually try `...WHERE b NOT IN...` (note the position of the NOT changed)

Comment: I added the invalid SQL to my question (the sub-select has an empty projection). Swapping the position of "NOT" does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
    SELECT DISTINCT b FROM EntityB AS b JOIN b.a AS a WHERE a IS NULL
```

If you can't, try that

```
    SELECT DISTINCT b FROM EntityB AS b JOIN b.a AS a WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Hm... `b.a` does not exist (there is no reverse relation from `EntityB` to `EntityA`, just the other way around)

Answer (score 0):

The EntityB doesn't know about which EntityA it belongs to. There might be some obscure or even some intuitive way of doing what you want to do in JPQL. But from my point of view you have failed to model your object model if you want to ask such questions.

"Hey B, what is your A - or is it non-exitent"
Will get answered by:
"What is "A"".

Adding information about its apparent relationship to A in B, will quickly resolve your current design problem.